# Error message received when clipping raster

Tags: qgis, raster, error, clip

QGIS 2.10.1 Pisa

Message -> Error: Computed -srcwin 8208 142185 0 0 has negative width and/or height.

Tried with several different files and types of raster files [GeoTIFF, MrSis, ECW], the same msg with different numbers.

Comment: Clipper needs to have both files in the same coordinate reference, is this the case with your files?

Comment: Thank you. Sorted out. Problem caused by different CRSs.

Answer (score 4):

Clipper and the other geoprocessing functions need to have all layers in the same coordinate reference system as they do not reproject them before they process the coordinates. That can leed to empty outputs, or much worse wrong outputs if the CRS are differing not much.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I keep getting the same error